# Can a modern web browser be embedded into an Excel sheet?

Tags: microsoft-excel, browser, microsoft-edge

I have a very specific use for a web browser embedded in an excel sheet (akin to inserting a chart), is this properly possible in 2023? This would be in a homogeneous windows environment only.

I'm aware of the ActiveX based web browser one can insert via the developer menu but its not clear to me if this can be trusted to not be IE11 and not disappear after an update.

Comment: For Excel for web not all features are available, you can refer to this article: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/differences-between-using-a-workbook-in-the-browser-and-in-excel-f0dc28ed-b85d-4e1d-be6d-5878005db3b6

Comment: That doesn't answer the question. The question is embedding a browser *inside* excel not the other way around. You can already embed what seems to be IE11 inside a sheet, I would like to know if one can successfully have a modern WebView2 (or other) inside excel.